# react.js don't render until ajax request finish

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have a pretty simple `React.js` component which I need to make an `isomorphic` (rendered on the server). The problem is that component rendered with helpful information only after `ajax` request completes, like that:

```
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {}
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/users/").then(response => {
      this.setState(users: response.data)
    })
  },

  render() {
    if (this.state.users == undefined) {
      return <div />
    }

    return <div>{this.state.users.map(some_function)}</div>
  }
})
```

The problem is that it's pointless to return empty `div` to search engines. I want `ajax` request to be finished (even on the server) and render only after that. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I believe that you want to take the parent component and use props instead of state, letting the parent component decide whether to render it or not.

Comment: @Dencker Could you explain how to decide render it or not, please?

Answer (score 6):

As touched on by @Dencker, you want to make the parent component decide when to render the child component, something like this would work:

```
// Parent
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      usersLoaded: false
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/users/").then(response => {
      this._users = response.users;
      this.setState({
        usersLoaded: true
      });
    })
  },

  render() {
    if ( this.state.usersLoaded ) {
      return (
        <ChildComponent users={this._users} />
      )
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
});

// Child
export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.users.map(some_function)}</div>
  }
});
```

What I'm doing there is:

1. Setting an initial state on the parent component which is `usersLoaded: false`.
2. In the render function for that component, making sure I only render the child component when the parent's `usersLoaded` state is true.
3. parent component's `componentDidMount` method is where the AJAX call takes place, and note I use a variable on the component to store the users, **not** the state object (states generally should only be used to store very simple values).
4. This is then passed down to the child component as a prop.

All of the above makes the child component far simpler as it will only now need a render method and no `if/else` check.

Comment: I'm following this approach, but server returns me a `<noscript data-react-checksum="-1280634584" data-reactid=".1l230yusxs0"></noscript>`

Comment: The question is how do you write tests, so it would wait until the render is not "null".