# Reactjs don't render until variable is ready

Tags: reactjs

I googled and found some relevant answers but they don't seem to be complete. eg. [react.js don't render until ajax request finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695444/react-js-dont-render-until-ajax-request-finish)

One of the answer suggest to put if else in template, and I have the following `Loader` component doing this:

```
var LoaderWrapper = function (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.loaded ? props.children :
                <div className="margin-fixer">
                    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-wave">
                        <div className="sk-rect1"></div>
                        <div className="sk-rect2"></div>
                        <div className="sk-rect3"></div>
                        <div className="sk-rect4"></div>
                        <div className="sk-rect5"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Now if I use this wrapper:

```
<LoaderWrapper loaded={variable!=null}>
    <MyComponent variable={variable}/>
</LoaderWrapper>
```

In `MyComponent`:

```
render () {
    const {variable} = this.props;
    return (<div>{variable.abc}</div>)
}
```

Problem is that  still complains about `variable` is null.

Also tried the following, complains about the same thing...

```
<LoaderWrapper loaded={false}>
    <MyComponent variable={variable}/>
</LoaderWrapper>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i block a React component to be rendered until I fetched all informations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022922/how-can-i-block-a-react-component-to-be-rendered-until-i-fetched-all-information)

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong, the following code still works and is based on your above idea

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


var LoaderWrapper = function (props) {

  return (
    <div>
      {props.loaded ? props.children :
        <h2> Loading ... </h2>}
    </div>
  )
};

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { variable } = this.props;
    return (<div>{variable.abc}</div>)
  }
}

class MyApp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { loaded: false };
    this.changeLoading();
  }

  changeLoading() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true
      })
    }, 2000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <LoaderWrapper loaded={this.state.loaded}>
        <MyComponent variable={{ abc: 'This is news' }} />
      </LoaderWrapper>
    )
  }

}

render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Please see here for working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q6wynn?file=index.js